# How to make certain elements unobtainable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a polyfill for IE and, as part of it, I fully believe I need to make some "fake" elements in the DOM.

As part of that, I want jQuery to consider them "nonexistent" when the user uses any of the functions to get jQuery-wrapped Elements from the DOM.
Here's an example:

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="exampleContainer">
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div data-fake class="2"></div>
    <div class="3"></div>
    <div data-fake class="4"></div>
    <div class="5"></div>
    <div class="6"></div>
</div>
```

If I use this code in jQuery:

```
var a = $("#exampleContainer").children().length;
var b = $("#exampleContainer > *").length;
```

Both a and b must count 4, not 6. Also:

```
var c = $("#exampleContainer > *").eq(2).prop('className');
```

c must be 5, not 3.
etc, etc, etc....

How do I do this with jQuery?

**Note:** I know the user can also use the DOM methods and properties directly but, at least for now, it is not a concern for me.

Comment: Minus is not mine. But it is a bad idea to do so. You have to implement the code in other way, where you don't need such hiding.

Comment: @Qwertiy I thought that also as an option but it isn't a good way of thinking given the situation we are in and the kind of knowledge we get. I cannot tell too much due to nda, unfortunately.

Comment: You have to catch calls to native dom methods, but I expect it to be impossible in old IE.

Comment: @Qwertiy I'm not worrying about the native DOM. These people only use either Mootools or jQuery and never the DOM directly so it's perfectly OK if it doesn't change the DOM and only changes jQuery

Comment: I meant you can't change jquery without changing dom methods. jquery passes calls to browser methods. Many jquery plugins are using browser methods. I think, it won't work if you try to filter jquery sets somehow.

Comment: @Qwertiy I can worry about each jQuery plugin at a time :). Even if I may release the code, I only need it to work inside a "sandbox". Having it well compatible with other plugins is not a concern at this point. Also, IIRC jQuery uses Sizzle for all the queries used except `#id`, `.class` and `[name=name]`. Sizzle then calls querySelectorAll() or crawls the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) polyfill if required):

```js
~function () {
  var ps = $.fn.pushStack;
  
  $.fn.pushStack = function (elems, name, args) {
    return ps.call(this, elems.filter(function (el) {
      return !$(el).is("[data-fake]");
    }), name, args);
  }
}();

alert([$("div").length, $("#exampleContainer > *").length])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="exampleContainer">
  <div class="1"></div>
  <div data-fake class="2"></div>
  <div class="3"></div>
  <div data-fake class="4"></div>
  <div class="5"></div>
  <div class="6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a great start! I like it! I'll now try dealing with the situations where that does work, for example: `$("#exampleContainer :first-child")`. If you can think of a way to solve it, feel free to update your answer and comment so that I know it. This is what I'm thinking so far (still in proof of concepts) https://jsfiddle.net/r4s2gL0h/